# C# interop automation while user interacts with separate Word instance

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Is there a way to run C# interop commands in the background that do not interfere with the user as they process separate word documents?

Answer (score 2):

All calls to the Office (for example, in Outlook) object model and PIA execute on Outlook’s main foreground thread. The only threading model that the Office/Outlook/Word object model supports is single-threaded apartment (STA). Calling the Office/Outlook/Word object model or PIA from a background thread is not supported and can lead to errors and unexpected results in your solution.